# Negative Cycles with Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, negative-number, bellman-ford

So I completely understand why negative edge weights will not work with Dijkstra's algorithm with an example like so:

```
       A
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   5       2
  /         \
  B--(-10)-->C
```

However, I have read that "if there is any negative cycle in graph you would never stop updating distance in vertices. This will cause a infinite loop." I don't understand how this would be the case if we declare vertices "done" when we visit them. How could we ever enter a cycle if we cannot revisit vertices we have already visited?

Comment: Depends on how you implement the algorithm. In a graph with no negative edges, there's no need to have a separate variable that marks a vertex as visited. A node that has been "visited" will never be visited again simply because it already has the shortest possible distance.

Comment: Dijkstra has an important property which every correctness proof relies on: Once a node is **settled**, the shortest path to that node is known. However, if you have negative weights, you can later find a path that is shorter, i.e. improves the cost. Then you would need to process the node and relax its arcs again. Then, the property is violated and the algorithm does not compute the shortest path anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version that you describe will indeed avoid loops.  It can also fail to discover the correct lowest cost path in cases where the lowest cost path has negative edges, but there is a more direct route without them.